# Discrepancy in using global variable in a function in Python

Tags: python

I was just playing around with Python and I came across something interesting which I didn't quite understand. The code goes as follows:

```py
a = 1
def function():
  print(a)
function()
print(a)
```

Here, a is a global variable and I used it in my function and the result was:

```
1
1
```

I was able to use a global variable locally in my function without having to use `global a` in my function.

Then, I experimented further with this:

```
a = 1
def function():
  a = a+1
  print(a)
function()
print(a)
```

When I ran this code, an error showed up and it said that the local variable `a` was referenced before assignment. I don't understand how before it recognized that a was a global variable without `global a`
but now I need `global a` like this

```py
a = 1
def function():
  global a
  a = a+1
  print(a)
function()
print(a)
```

in order for this code to work. Can someone explain this discrepancy?

Comment: When you assign a variable in a function, you create a local variable. Now that you've done that you have a global `a` and a local `a`. Now you say `a + 1`, which `a` are you referring to. Python wants you to be explicit here. When you just read the value, there's no confusion because there is only the global `a`.

Comment: local variable is created only when you use assignment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

You can read the value from a global variable anytime, but the `global` keyword allows you to change its value.

This is because when you try and set the `a` variable in your function, by default it will create a new local function variable named `a`. In order to tell python you want to update the global variable instead, you need to use the `global` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

When creating "=" ,a new variable inside a function python does not check if that variable is a global variable, it treats that new variable as a new local variable, and since you are assigning it to itself and it does not exist locally yet, it then triggers the error

Comment: That's not an analogy; that is *literally* how Python works. An assignment in a function makes the name local to the function, even if the assignment statement isn't executed at run-time. Locality is a *static* property.

Comment: I agree with you.